# Connection Lifetime=0 in MySql connection string

Tags: .net, sql, mysql, connection-string

What exactly does `Connection Lifetime=0` mean in a connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: A value of zero (0) causes pooled connections to have the maximum connection timeout.

[Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html).

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233488/connection-lifetime0-in-mysql-connection-string/3444881#3444881

Comment: i can't delete this answer as it's accepted and poster hasn't been seen for 2 years.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my research I believe that [Myra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233488/connection-lifetime-0-in-mysql-connection-string/1233557#1233557) is the closest of the other answers.

It is *not* the same as the connection timeout.

Instead see this pseudocode from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/angelsb/ado-net-the-misunderstood-connection-lifetime-managed-pooler-connection-string-keyword) article:

```
On SqlConnection.Close

   Check if time the connection has been open is greater than Connection Lifetime if it is, throw the connection away

   Else Put connection on the pool
```

The same article explains why you would rarely want to use this property (and the situations in which you might).

Note that it has been renamed to "Load Balance Timeout" in an attempt to clarify its behavior per the above article.

Answer (score 2):

In addition,
When you use Connection LifeTime:
It destroys pooled connections
If the time your connection is opened for is larger than Connection LifeTime,connection is not usable.

I suggest that using Connection LifeTime if you have not a connection within a cluster of server

Answer (score -1):

It means there is no connection time out period. For example if it is set 300 if in this time query is not completed, let's say because there is lot of data, a time out exception will be thrown. When it is say 0 it will work until query is completed.

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233488/connection-lifetime0-in-mysql-connection-string/3444881#3444881